How can I restore the cpu status? (restoring the cpu registers x86_64)
I am implementing context switching for my first os and I came into a little problem I cannot solve which is restoring the cpu status after saving it from a struct. As all the registers have to be preserved I cannot use a temporary register
here is my struct:
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Default)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct CPUStatus {    
    pub rsp: u64,
    pub rflags: u64,
    pub ss: u64,
    pub cs: u64,

    pub rip: u64,
    
    r15: u64,
    r14: u64,
    r13: u64,
    r12: u64,
    r11: u64,
    r10: u64,
    r9: u64,
    r8: u64,

    rbp: u64,
    rdi: u64,
    rsi: u64,

    rdx: u64, 
    rcx: u64,
    rbx: u64,
    rax: u64,
}

my save code:
    pub extern "C" fn save_inner(self) -> Self {
        self
    }

    pub extern "C" fn save() -> Self {
        unsafe {        
            asm!("
            push rax
            push rbx
            push rcx
            push rdx
            
            push rsi
            push rdi
            push rbp
            
            push r8
            push r9
            push r10
            push r11
            push r12
            push r13
            push r14
            push r15

            push 0
            push 0x8
            push 0x10
            pushfq 
            push 0 // rsp
            call {}
            add rsp, {}
            ret
            ", sym Self::save_inner, const core::mem::size_of::<CPUStatus>() + 8, options(noreturn))
        }
    }

I tried this, obviously it gives too many registers used in inline assembly error:
pub extern "C" fn restore(self) -> ! {
        unsafe {
            asm!("
            mov rax, {}
            mov rbx, {}
            mov rcx, {}
            mov rdx, {}

            mov rsi, {}
            mov rdi, {}
            mov rbp, {}

            mov r8, {}
            mov r9, {}
            mov r10, {}
            mov r11, {}
            mov r12, {}
            mov r13, {}
            mov r14, {}
            mov r15, {}
            
            mov rsp, {}
            push {}
            popfq
            jmp {}
            ", 
            in(reg) self.rax, 
            in(reg) self.rbx,
            in(reg) self.rcx,
            in(reg) self.rdx,

            in(reg) self.rsi,
            in(reg) self.rdi,
            in(reg) self.rbp,

            in(reg) self.r8,
            in(reg) self.r9,
            in(reg) self.r10,
            in(reg) self.r11,
            in(reg) self.r12,
            in(reg) self.r13,
            in(reg) self.r14,
            in(reg) self.r15,

            in(reg) self.rsp,
            in(reg) self.rflags,            
            in(reg) self.rip, options(noreturn))
        }
 }
}

How is one supposed to solve that?

Why wouldn't you do this in assembler .s files, where you have complete control?  Have you looked at the methods Linux uses to do this?  BTW, in your restore, it's better to push the return address and do a ret.

i have no idea how to take a look at linux's methods, tysm for the ret reminder i think that is the key, i will also consider using pure asm or global_asm! instead thanks!

@TimRoberts separate assembly files aren't as easy to use in Rust applications as Rust embedded assembly. global_asm is a good way to go in this particular case

fixed using the iretq instruction and global_asm!
global_asm!("
.global restore_cpu_status
restore_cpu_status:
    // push the iretq frame
    push [rdi + 16]     // push ss
    push [rdi]          // push rsp
    push [rdi + 8]      // push rflags
    push [rdi + 24]     // push cs
    push [rdi + 32]     // push rip

    
    mov r15, [rdi + 40]    
    mov r14, [rdi + 48]    
    mov r13, [rdi + 56]    
    mov r12, [rdi + 64]    
    mov r11, [rdi + 72]    
    mov r10, [rdi + 80]    
    mov r9, [rdi + 88]    
    mov r8, [rdi + 96]    

    mov rbp, [rdi + 104]

    mov rsi, [rdi + 120]

    mov rdx, [rdi + 128]
    mov rcx, [rdi + 136]
    mov rbx, [rdi + 144]
    mov rax, [rdi + 152]

    mov rdi, [rdi + 112]

    iretq
");

here is the function definition
extern "C" { pub fn restore_cpu_status(status: &CPUStatus); }

